# why cant npm find file when making react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

Every time I run `npx create-react-app my-app` I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path foo:\bar\node_modules\react
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'foo:\bar\node_modules\react'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I've been looking for a fix all day but cant seem to get past it.

Comment: Did you try `npm i create-react-app`?

Comment: @DreamBold i ran that line and im now getting the same error on create-react-app but with a different path: no such file or directory, mkdir 'foo:\bar\node_modules\cra-template'.

I followed that up with npm i cra-template and then ran create-react-app and i still got the "cra-template" error.

Answer (score 1):

*You can try*

```
npm cache clean --force
npm i create-react-app
```

*You can delete both node_modules and package-lock.json*

```
run npm i web-vitals --save-dev
run npm install
```

and then you can use npm run build and npm start again.

*If these don't work, you can try*

```
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```

and then `npx create-react-app your-app.` Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This might not solve anyone elses issue but it might be worth a try if you absolutely cant find your answer anywhere:

oddly enough even though I had access to all my drives, after I physically disconnected and re-connected them all I no longer had the error.